# lc-3 how to add integer value to a register

Tags: integer, sum, lc3

I am new to LC-3 and trying to write simple programs.
I am trying to load two integers 2, 3 into 2 different registers and print the sum out.
Here is my program and instead of adding 2 and 3, it is adding 32 and 33 and giving me the corresponding ascii character for 65. How do I fix the program so that it prints 5? Also, I know OUT prints the value of R0 but How would I print the value of R1 and R2?
Is there another way to load an integer value to registers other than using LD?

.ORIG x3000

```
    LD R1, TWO
    LD R2, THREE

    ADD R2, R2, R1
    ADD R0, R2, #0
    OUT

           TRAP x25
```

TWO .FILL x32
THREE .FILL x33

```
            .END
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are putting x32 and x33 into the TWO and THREE memory addresses, so why are you expecting them to only have x2 and x3? Just put x2 and x3 into them instead. To print the value of R1 and R2, you should do it like you have in your code where you transfer it over and then do OUT. If you wanted a little more complicated way, you could work with the Data Status Register and use the Data Display Register to directly print registers other than R0 to the screen. As far as loading integers into registers, LD is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

**Your code:**

```
TWO .FILL x32
THREE .FILL x33
```

**Answer:**

x32 is ASCII 2, and x## is ASCII 3. You assume that ASCII values are used - you just want regular decimal values!

**Note:**

Being under decimal 16, hex "x2" and "x3" are equivalent to decimal 2 and 3. You can also use "#2" or just "2".